# local variables in print method

Tags: java, methods, computer-science, local-variables, bluej

I have wrote a print method which tell the user congratulates on their, but at the same time i have another field called Downloads, I wouls like to update the field downloads once the thr print method have been invoked, thanks 
and im using bluej

Comment: Is there a question? I can't see any apart from your `wishlist`.

Comment: The implicit question is pretty clear, I think.  "How do I update the `downloads` field once the print method has been invoked?"

Comment: where is downloads field? the question is hard to comprehend until explained clearly.

Comment: this is the field private int noOdDownloads;

Comment: yes, so whats wrong in your existing code? It's doing exactly that. Also you could optimize your code by looking at gefei's answer

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
int num;
 this.noOdDownloads = num;
 this.noOdDownloads = num + 1;
```

do

```
 this.noOdDownloads++;
```

your original program has two problems: 1) `num` is not instantiated, this is what the compiler will complain, and 2) even if you instantiated it, say with `int num=0;`, 
`num` is actually a local  variable in the method. every time the method is run, the local variable is instantiated again and reset to `0`. When you then assign its value to `noOdDownloads`, the latter is reset to `0` too.

Comment: can you please explain it, thanks guys

Comment: i edited my answer an put some explanation in it